# Svelte application bug: converting string to boolean in the view fails

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

In a Svelte app, I have this array of countries:

```
let countries = [
    {
        name:"Alegeria",
        status: "1"
    },
    {
        name:"Bulgaria",
        status :"0"
    }
]
```

Note the `status` property is a string. I iterate the array this way:

```
{#if countries.length > 0}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th class="text-right">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {#each countries as c}  
        <tr>
            <td>{c.name}</td>
            <td class="text-right"><Switch bind:checked={Boolean(Number(c.status))} /></td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
    </tbody>
</table>
{:else}
<p class="alert alert-danger">No countries found</p>
{/if}
```

As you can see, I try  to convert the value of the `status` property to a boolean this by using `Boolean(Number(c.status))`.

Instead of the desired conversion I get the error: `Can only bind to an identifier (e.g.` foo`) or a member expression` as the **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5c58f3e340d1451f96abcfca621ecb56?version=3.9.1)**  shows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you bind directly to the countries status? Does it have to be 0 and 1 instead of false and true?

Comment: @Gh05d I would still have to convert the strings `"0"` and `"1"` to tha numbers the strings `0` and `1`. So I would have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says in the error, you can only `bind` to an identifier or member expression - ie a variable.

This is because a `bind` is a two-way thing, and if you have applied `Boolean(Number(())` to it, when someone changes that input, then svelte doesn't know how to undo those functions to 'save' the data back into that variable it's bound to.

If you can't change the status variables to be boolean (better solution, as suggested by other answers), you need to manually do this two-way updating. Drop the `bind`, just have `checked={Boolean(Number(c.status))}`, and handle the input's `change` event to convert from true/false back into "1" or "0", and save that to the status.

Use:

```
function handleClick(country) {
    countries.find(c => c.name == country.name).status = (country.status == "1") ? "0" :"1"
}
```

and

```
<Switch checked={Boolean(Number(c.status))} on:change={() => handleClick(c)}/>
```

See it working in [this repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/dbdc1a765c3a432aa6105e7692dbed42?version=3.24.0)

Comment: I need to change the `countries` array (the data has to be saved in a database) si I guess  I can't dich `bind`.

Comment: I mean you can change it without bind. (Updated the answer with a working code example)

Comment: I use Switch not Checkbox

Comment: Well you haven't mentioned how you are defining `Switch`, so I can't help you there.
I only used a checkbox in my demo code that I wrote for you so that it could work, and you could see an example of manually defining a binding between a variable and input box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the [Boolean()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) function creates a new object, to which you can't bind, because it is never again referenced. You can bind directly to your array of values in `countries`, using this code:

```
{#each countries as c, index}   
    <tr>
        <td>{c.name}</td>
        <td class="text-right"><Switch bind:checked={countries[index].status} /></td>
    </tr>
{/each}
```

What has changed is that you use the `index` parameter of the `#each` loop now to bind to the variable of the countries array. Please be aware that in order for this to properly work, you need to change the status values to `true` or `false`. Otherwise it will still work, but the initial value will always be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want pass the value down to the `Switch` component, simply remove the `bind:` like so:

```
<td class="text-right"><Switch checked={Boolean(Number(c.status))} /></td>
```

If you want to update the countries model via the switch component, I suggest to forward the click event and use a simple click handler method, something like this:

```
    function onClick(event, country) {
        countries = countries.map(c => {
            if (c.name ===  country.name) {
                c.status = event.target.checked ? '1' : '0';
            }
            return c;
        })
    }

    ...

    <td class="text-right"><Switch checked={c.status === '1'} on:click={(e) => onClick(e, c)}/></td>
```

full code on REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/013286229d3847c1895c4977aee234af?version=3.9.1